# javascript confirm() ok and cancel return same result

Tags: javascript, confirm

This is my code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="del('Are you sure you want to Delete?')">

<script language="JavaScript">
function del(display) 
{   
    var inputs = document.myform;   

    if(inputs[5].value != '')
    {
        confirm(display);  
    }
}
</script>
```

When I click either the "ok" or the "cancel", they both did the same way (the OK way)

How can I make the "cancel" do what it is supposed to do?

NOTE: I have a form there that I didn't include for the simplicity of question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="return del('Are you sure you want to Delete?')">

<script language="JavaScript">
function del(display) 
{   
    var inputs = document.myform;   

    if(inputs[5].value != '')
    {
        return confirm(display);  
    }
}
</script>
```

you need to add two `return` in your code (both `onclick` attribute and inside `del()` function). You should also return something if your condition `inputs[5].value != ''` is false

Answer (score 3):

change your code like this.

```
onclick="return del('Are you sure you want to Delete?')"

    if(inputs[5].value != '')
        {
            return confirm(display);  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this;

```
onclick="return del('Are you sure you want to Delete?')"
```